# Office Live and LibreOffice 3.3 compat issue

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, libreoffice, docx

I have a compatibility question.  I am using Office Live to edit .docx files online.  But when I download the .docx files down to my Macbook pro (running snow leopard) and I try to open the .docx file in LibreOffice 3.3 I get the below error - but this doesn't happen on a Windows system.  Is this a Mac issue, Office Live issue, or a LibreOffice on Mac issue or a little of all 3?[image: Screen Shot of LibreOffice error]

Comment: I believe LibreOffice may be a fork of OpenOffice.org.  Can you open that document with the most recent version of OpenOffice.org?

Comment: let me download and get back to you.

Comment: If it opens in OOo (OpenOffice.org), then try using OOo to then save it with a different name and load that new file in LibreOffice -- hopefully this will resolve your problem (and if it does, then it means that LibreOffice is unable to read that particular document).

Comment: Downloaded OpenOffice 3.3 same result.  I think this has to do with the way the Office Live saves their .docx files

Comment: @Jeremy Hajek:  Try copying your suspect .docx file to a .zip file, then see if you can open it with 7-Zip ( http://sevenzip.sourceforge.net/ ) or some other .Zip file manager.  If you can't open it, then that is a pretty clear indication that Office Live is NOT saving it properly.

Comment: Good thinking.  I changed the .docx in question and saved it as a .zip then I was able to open the zip file proper and see all the directory structures.

Comment: @Jeremy Hajek:  That's a step in the right direction -- you've just confirmed that the .docx file is likely in the correct format.  So, the next step now is to open this file and save it in a format that other word processors can understand.  If the document isn't a very complex one (e.g., it includes tables with formulas, etc.), then just about any other format also supported by the others should do (in the "Save as..." dialogue there should be a "file type" option in there somewhere; it's typically immediately below the filename entry box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LibreOffice website](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/writer/) says:

> To guarantee that your documents can be opened by the widest range of products and far into the future, save your documents in OpenDocument format, the new international standard for text documents. This XML-based format means that people opening your files are not obliged to use Writer: they can be accessed using any OpenDocument-compliant software.
>
> Writer easily reads Microsoft Word documents, and you can also save your work in Microsoft Word format, for sending to people still locked into Microsoft products. LibreOffice can also open .docx files created with Microsoft Office 2007 for Windows or Microsoft Office 2008 for Mac OS X.

If you want some additional info, you can ask on their [Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/libreoffice.org).

Comment: Can you just post up a question on their facebook page?

Comment: There must be some bug so I will post on the facebook page and see what comes of it.